# Consecutive values in strings, getting indices

Tags: python, string, indexing, splice

The following is a python string of length of approximately +1000.

```
string1 = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBB........AAAAXXXXX"
len(string1)  ## 1311
```

I would like to know the index of where the consecutive X's end and the non-X characters begin. Reading this string from left to right, the first non-X character is at index location 22, and the first non-X character from the right is at index location 1306.

How does one find these indices?

My guess would be:

```
for x in string1:
    if x != "X":
        print(string.index(x))
```

The problem with this is it outputs all indices that are not X. It does not give me the index where the consecutive X's end.

Even more confusing for me is how to "check" for consecutive X's. Let's say I have this string:

```
string2 = "XXXXAAXAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBB........AAAAXXXXX"
```

Here, the consecutive X's end at index 4, not index 7. How could I check several characters ahead whether this is really no longer consecutive?

Comment: Are you looking for all consecutive X? In your example there are different consecutive X sequences in the string. Also, how exactly are you collecting them? What is the structure of your expected output?

Comment: @idjaw Just a simple string. I want to know where consecutive X's end. The string is given. The output should just be the index where there are no longer consecutive X's.

Comment: OK, but for example in your first string, the beginning has a sequence of X, but then at the end of the same string there is another sequence of X. Are you looking just for the first?

Comment: @idjaw No, I want both indices. In these strings, the consecutive X's are only at the very beginning and at the very end. Sorry---I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Right. That is what I thought. So, how do you want to display this? Are you looking to collect this in some structure like `[(0, 10), (200, 224)]` for example? You should probably edit in the question the specifics of that too.

Comment: No, I simply need the outputs for the indices. I'm then going to put them in `randint(first_index, second_index)`

Comment: @ShanZhengYang I updated the answer, I hope that's what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well your question, you just do:

```
def getIndexs(string):
  lst =[]
  flag = False
  for i, char in enumerate(string):

    if char == "x":
      flag = True

    if ((char != "x") and flag):
      lst.append(i-1)
      flag = False


  return lst


print(getIndexs("xxxxbbbxxxxaaaxxxbb"))
```

> [3, 10, 16]

Answer (score 2):

using regex, split the first & last group of `X`s, get their lengths to construct the indices.

```
import re

mystr = 'XXXXAAXAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBB........AAAAXXXXX'
xs = re.split('[A-W|Y-Z]+', mystr)
indices = (len(xs[0]), len(mystr) - len(xs[-1]) - 1)
# (4, 47)
```

> I simply need the outputs for the indices. I'm then going to put them in `randint(first_index, second_index)`

Its possible to pass the indices to the function like this

```
randint(*indices)
```

However, I suspect that you want to use the output of `randint(first_index, last_index)` to select a random character from the middle, this would be a shorter alternative.

```
from random import choice
randchar = choice(mystr.strip('X'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the sequences are, as you say, only in the beginning and at the end of your string, a simple loop / reversed loop would suffice:

```
string1 = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBB........AAAAXXXXX"

left_index = 0
for char in string1:
    left_index += 1
    if char != "X":
         break

right_index = len(string1)
for char in reversed(string1):
    if char != "X":
         break
    right_index -= 1

print(left_index)  # 22
print(right_index)  # 65
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex can `lookahead` and identify characters that don't match the pattern:

`>>>[match.span() for match in re.finditer(r'X{2,}((?=[^X])|$)', string2)]
[(0, 4), (48, 53)]`

Breaking this down:

- X - the character we're matching
- {2,} - need to see at least two in a row to consider a match
- `(`(?=[^X])`|`$`)` - two conditions will satisfy the match

  - (?=[^X]) - lookahead for anything *but* an `X`
  - $ - the end of the string

As a result, finditer returns each instance where there are multiple X's, followed by a non-X or an end of line.  `match.span()` extracts the position information from each match from the string.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the first index and last index (of non-'X' character).

```
s = 'XXABCDXXXEFGHXXXXX'

first_index = len(s) - len(s.lstrip('X'))
last_index = len(s.rstrip('X')) - len(s) - 1
```

print first_index, last_index

> > 2 -6

## How it works:

### For first_index:

We strip all the 'X' characters at the beginning of our string. Finding the difference in length between the original and shortened string gives us the index of the first non-'X' character.

### For last_index:

Similarly, we strip the 'X' characters at the end of our string. We also subtract 1 from the difference, since reverse indexing in Python starts from -1.

### Note:

If you just want to randomly select one of the characters between first_index and last_index, you can do:

```
import random
shortened_s = s.strip('X')
random.choice(shortened_s)
```

Comment: for `first_index` & `last_index`, the expression would be simpler if `lstrip` & `rstrip` are used respectively, instead of `strip`.

Comment: @HaleemurAli Right, this is much simpler!